# Iterating through an array (Swift)

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I have an array, `photoAsset`, and I am trying to delete each item listed in the array from an asset collection.  How do I go about doing this?

This is what I have tried

```
    PHPhotoLibrary.sharedPhotoLibrary().performChanges({ () -> Void in

        let request = PHAssetCollectionChangeRequest(forAssetCollection: self.assetCollection)

        //This is the number of items in my array
        println(self.photosAsset.count)

        //Only removes the FIRST item, need to remove ALL items
        request.removeAssets([self.photosAsset[0]])


        }, completionHandler: nil)
```

Comment: Why? The request array is defined in the scope of the block and will be released after its finished. Why remove them all?

Comment: For the function of my app, the button is to remove all photos in the library.  I could go into detail of the functionality of my app but that would be pointless.  I figured out the answer and posted it if you are curious.

Comment: What is in your `self.photoAsset` array?  Are the elements `PHAsset` objects or arrays of `PHAsset` objects?

Answer (score 2):

Why not `request.removeAssets(self.photosAsset)` rather than removing them one by one in a loop?

Answer (score 0):

I feel like an idiot, completely forgot about a for loop smh...  Here is the answer.

```
        let request = PHAssetCollectionChangeRequest(forAssetCollection: self.assetCollection)

        self.photosAsset.count
        for (var i=0; i<self.photosAsset.count; i++) {
        request.removeAssets([self.photosAsset[i]])
        }

        }, completionHandler: nil)
```